# MVC Security: ViewModel vs. [Bind()] annotation. Are both needed, or is one or the other enough?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, entity-framework-6

I've been searching for an answer to this question, as I want my code to be as secure as possible.

Are `ViewModel` and `[Bind()]` equivalent when it comes to security?

**Detailed Explanation**

Let's say for example you have the following Model:

**Model.cs**

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(Regex, ErrorMessage = RegexError)]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Something { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(Regex, ErrorMessage = RegexError)]
    [StringLength(40, MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string SomethingElse { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(Regex, ErrorMessage = RegexError)]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string AnotherSomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

**ModelController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Something([Bind(Include="Something,SomethingElse")] Model model)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
```

In this scenario, I am using the `[Bind()]` annotation to exclude other data from whatever `Something(Model model)` is doing. I'm only allowing the input that I want.

But what happens if I use a `ViewModel` instead? Like this:

**ModelViewModel.cs**

```
public class ModelViewModel
{
    // Security annotations intentionally removed to keep question compact.
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

...do I still need to use `[Bind()]` in `Something(Model model)`? Are these independent of each other, or do they both work in the same way when it comes to excluding unwanted columns for updating?

Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are absolutely equivalent and secure enough. Using `ViewModel` seems more natural though. There's no need in keeping a long string list of properties that are allowed to be bound. The view model does this purpose. If you use the view model you don't need any `Bind()` attributes. The properties of the view model dictate what gets deserialized from the request. Everything else is thrown away.

Comment: This answers another important question I had as well, "Is there an alternative to keeping a long list of properties in `[Bind()]`?" Good to know I can get rid of the `[Bind()]` attributes. `ViewModels` are very powerful!